# MouseOver and MouseOut events does not get fired by a widget

Tags: gwt, event-handling, mouseevent, mouseover

I have two widgets listening for a MouseOutEvent. Problem is that sometimes this events does not get called on both of the widgeth even if you mouse out of them. 
No error is thrown and this is extremely hard to debug. 
My understanding is that this event is fired by a browser, so I don't understand why this is not happening. I am registering this event to the widget itself.

Any suggestions will be a great help.

Thanks

Comment: You should debug that the eventlistener is really added, I had cases where GWT doesn't added the listener. You should also check that there are no other DOM element lie over your widget element and that the widget element really has the width and height you expected, some elements that contains floating elements doesn't have a height for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might have used addHandler to register to your MouseOverHandler. Widget has two methods for adding event handlers, addDomHandler and addHandler. The first is meant to be used for DomEvents, e.g. MouseOutEvents. It sinks the event on the widget, which means that your listener will get notified (this is only necessary for DomEvents). Those events might not get fired if you do not use addDomHandler to register your handler.